# Rails: update mutiple attribute of multiple model concurrently

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, update-attributes

I want to update values taken from a single form in two different model at the same time, I have written the following code to do so :-

```
if @mess.update_attributes!(:mess_name => params[:mess_name_update], :mess_capacity => params[:mess_capacity_update]) && @mess_price.update_attributes!(:breakfast_charge => params[:mess_breakfast_charge_update], :lunch_charge => params[:mess_lunch_charge_update], :dinner_charge => params[:mess_dinner_charge_update], :monthly_charge => params[:mess_monthly_charge_update], :semesterly_charge => params[:mess_semesterly_charge_update], :start_date => params[:start_date_update], :end_date => params[:end_date_update], :rebate => params[:rebate_update])
      flash[:success] = "Mess Details Updated Successfully!!"
    else
      flash[:error] = "Some Error! Please Try Again!"
    end
```

But the above code is giving following error

> ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid
>
> Validation failed: Start date can't be blank

Following is the two schema I am using, for **@mess** its **MessType** model and for **@mess_price** its **MessPrice** model:

```
MessType
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field         | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| mess_id       | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| mess_name     | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| mess_capacity | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| start_date    | date         | No   |     | NULL    |                |
| created_at    | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at    | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

MessPrice
+-------------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field             | Type     | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                | int(11)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| breakfast_charge  | float    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| lunch_charge      | float    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| dinner_charge     | float    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| monthly_charge    | float    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| semesterly_charge | float    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| rebate            | float    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| start_date        | date     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| end_date          | date     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| mess_id           | int(11)  | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| created_at        | datetime | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at        | datetime | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Comment: `update_attributes!` should not be changing the values in `params`. Did you check the `params` values with a debug statement prior to your `if` to see if the value was `nil` to begin with?

Comment: @mbratch yes I have checked `params` values they are returning values not `null`

Comment: That should not be a problem. Did you try interchanging the model updates? update second model first and then first model. You should not see any difference.

Comment: `update_attributes!` doesn't change `params`. The error message you show isn't the exact message (I assume it really should say `start_date` not `Start date`) so it's unclear. If it says the "start_date" is blank, then it thinks `params[:start_date_update]` is blank or nil. Your rails console log should show the whole params hash when the controller is called. Can you show that params hash dump? Copy/paste so it's exact?

Comment: @mbratch I cant paste it in comment its too long

Comment: You could just paste the params hash dump. Is the params hash by itself really huge?

Comment: @JSWorld I already tried to do what you said but the problem is same second one making null

Comment: @mbratch yes its huge :(

Comment: Can you copy/paste the part of the params hash that shows the value of `:start_date_update`? There must be a subset of the params hash that you could show from the log. Also, when you did what @JSWorld suggested, did you get exactly the same error message? There's something going on that's hard to determine because you are showing very little context of the problem. I'm sure it's something simple.

Comment: @mbratch this is my params hash for `:start_date_update` :
`"start_date_update"=>"2013-06-01"`

Comment: @mbratch you were write the problem was simple my `@mess` model having start_date field so i removed that, you can answer my question i am adding extra details to question

Answer (score 1):

I recommend installing the `awesome_print` gem - https://github.com/michaeldv/awesome_print

```
# add to Gemfile
gem 'awesome_print'
# install
bundle
```

Then the first thing in your controller action do

```
logger.debug " -----------"
logger.ap params
logger.debug " -----------"
```

Check your log file `log/development.log` for the output, it could be the params are coming across correctly but not what you expect?
some of the attributes might be nested in another hash key and need to be accessed via `params[:something][:xyz]`

I would also recommend making the code more readable and running it in a transaction

```
@mess.mess_name = params[:mess_name_update]
@mess.mess_capacity = params[:mess_capacity_update]

@mess_price.breakfast_charge = params[:mess_breakfast_charge_update]
@mess_price.lunch_charge = params[:mess_lunch_charge_update]
@mess_price.dinner_charge = params[:mess_dinner_charge_update]
@mess_price.monthly_charge = params[:mess_monthly_charge_update]
@mess_price.semesterly_charge = params[:mess_semesterly_charge_update]
@mess_price.start_date = params[:start_date_update]
@mess_price.end_date = params[:end_date_update]
@mess_price.rebate = params[:rebate_update]

# NOTE: an alternative to above is to name your html input fields the rails way
# so that params are sent in a nested hash, i.e. "mess_price[start_date]" -> params[:mess_price][:start_date]
# then you can do @mess_price.update_attributes(params[:mess_price])
# using form_for html helper will automatically apply this style of naming to html input fields

Mess.transaction do 
  # you might want save! vs save - depends if you show validation error in the UI or not
  if @mess.save && @mess_price.save
    flash[:success] = "Mess Details Updated Successfully!!"
  else
    # don't save changes, show validation errors
    raise ActiveRecord::Rollback 
    flash[:error] = "Some Error! Please Try Again!"
  end
end
```